# Spreading elements in Vuetify's VAppBar

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I'm building an app using Vuetify and I'm trying to spread out my buttons on the app bar. So I assign `d-flex` and `justify-space-between` classes to `VAppBar` but it doesn't work.

Turns out `VAppBar` actually consists of an outer `<header>` element and a `<div class="v-toolbar__content">` element which only grows as wide as its children. The `justify-space-between` is applied only to the `<header>` element while the contents of `VAppBar` is placed in the `<div>`. `VSpacer` between my buttons won't work because `VSpacer` doesn't push its parent. Wrapping my buttons with a `<div>` and setting it to 100% width won't work either because it would just be 100% the width of `v-toolbar__content`

Any workaround to this? Is there a convention on spreading things across `VAppBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to *not* assign `d-flex` on the `VAppBar`. The app bar is already a flexbox aligned to the middle and `justify-*` & `align-*` classes works just fine.